# How to Pass data from class to Form using get set method?

Tags: c#, class

I am a beginner in c#. I have array data in TCP class and it passes to form I tried to Get a Value ,but I got 0 value from return the data to form

tcp.cs

```
public class Tcp
    {
        private int _a;
        public void start()
        {
            int[] i = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            a = i[0];
        }
        public int a
        {
            get
            {
                return _a;
            }
            set
            {
                _a = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Form.cs

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tcp t = new Tcp();
        Console.WriteLine(t.a);
    }
```

Comment: Does `t.a` not work?

Comment: yes I got 0 value

Comment: You didn't call `start()`... The default value of an `int` is `0`. If no other value is assigned to it, that's what it will be.

Comment: You need to call t.start method.

Comment: I call but I got error  Console.WriteLine(t.start()); Arugument connot convert to void to bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, Use must Call start For Initializing a:

```
public class Tcp
    {
        private int _a;
        public void start()
        {
            int[] i = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            a = i[0];
        }
        public int a
        {
            get
            {
                return _a;
            }
            set
            {
                _a = value;
            }
        }
    }

        Tcp t = new Tcp();
        t.start();
        Console.WriteLine(t.a);
```